# Reference counting of UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, automatic-ref-counting

I just experienced a strange behavior when I do the following steps,

1. In a view controller method, create a View controller instance (local instance).
2. Add the view as a subview to the view controller's view.

The view is displayed properly. The view has a button and when I click the button,  it crashes with `EXEC_BAD-ACCESS`. After debugging a while, found that the view controller instance is release and button click event is not fired since the controller doesnot exist.

When I moved the declaration of the view controller to class level, it started working. I feel if a view controller's view is on the screen, shouldn't the view controller instance be retained.

Any thoughts?

Some code pointer.

```
class SomeViewController:UIViewController{
      var workingVC:SomeVC?
      func crashingMethod()
      {
          let vc:SomeVC = SomeVC(nibName:"SomeVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
          let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
          let applWindow:UIWindow = delegate.window!
          applWindow.addSubview(vc.view)

      }

     func workingMethod()
      {
          self.workingVC = SomeVC(nibName:"SomeVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
          let delegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate
          let applWindow:UIWindow = delegate.window!
          applWindow.addSubview(self.workingVC!.view)

      }

}
```

Comment: A UIView can't retain a UIViewController, because the UIViewController already retains the UIView. This would lead to a circular reference and nothing would ever get deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create object like this

```
let vc:SomeVC = SomeVC(nibName:"SomeVC", bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

object lifetime is equal to scope where it is created.
When scope ends, ARC release this object and all associated objects.

But, when you add it on class level, lifetime of this object equal to lifetime of owner(SomeViewController). So, it is released only when owner released.

Is it clear for you?
Also you can read about it in [Memory Management Section in Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Comment: I got the ARC and figured out the scope aspects. However I specifically wanted to know if a view is in memory the view controller backing it up would be released it or not.

Comment: View? Another view? Or what kind of view?

Comment: Just UIView whose next responder is UIViewcontroller

Comment: No, it wouldn't. If you keep strong ref to UIViewController.

Comment: Yeah Mathias comment explained the root cause, cyclic strong reference is a memory leak...